# Heap corruption when deleting global array

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, delete-operator, heap-corruption

The following code seems to be causing heap corruption whenever the debugger hits the `delete[]` operator.  It's trying to delete a global array of structures which was defined as an `extern` in the header file and then declared in the global scope of the main .cpp file.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
  switch(msg) 
  { 
    case WM_CREATE: 
      { 
        int main_win_x, main_win_y;

        tiles_horiz = 10;  //temp code
        tiles_vert = 10;   //temp code
        num_mines = 5;    //temp code

        main_win_x = (tiles_horiz * 22) + 20;
        main_win_y = (tiles_vert * 22) + 20;

        MoveWindow(hwnd, 100, 100, main_win_x, main_win_y, TRUE);

        tiles_total = (tiles_horiz * tiles_vert);
        tile_array = new tile[tiles_total];

        SetupPlayField();
        DrawInitTiles(hwnd);
      }
      break;
    case WM_SIZE:
      {

      }
      break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
      delete[] tile_array;
      DestroyWindow(hwnd);
      break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    default:
      return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've searched various heap corruptions topics on forums the last couple of days and so far have come up dry trying various things.

One person suggested that maybe the pointer to my array tile_array had changed by the time the program hits `delete[]`.  But I've checked this the a couple of times and the address of both the pointer and the first element of the array remain the same.

Other forum answer from other people's posts usually suggest that I may be deleting the array more than once, but so far this is the only time the `delete[]` operator is used for that specific array.

Comment: Not seeing how tile_array is initially setup, but since it is extern and global, is there any chance at all it is being deleted by someone else as well? set a bp on your allocation, using vs-debugger establish a break-on-write after you've written your data, and see if anyone else is hitting it. chances are, they are (or you are).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try and take the time to properly format your code; it makes your question more readable and improves your chances of getting a quick answer. Please replace tab characters with spaces. You can format the code by pasting it into the text area, selecting it all, and using `Ctrl+K` or the toolbar button with the `{}` characters. (You can also format it by indenting each line by four or more characters.) You can preview it as you're formatting in an almost WYSYWIG style right below the text area where you're entering it. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing every access to the title_array it is hard to speculate on the cause of this problem. With memory corruption where the program shows up isn't always what caused it.

One thing that you may want to check is that the extern declaration is for a "tile* tile_array " and not "tile tile_array []". I very much so doubt this is the case, but when dealing with extern and arrays I have seen this mistake bite a few people.

Another thing I would do is make sure to NULL out tile_array after deleting it and when you declare it. If the problem goes away when you do this then it was in fact either a too early delete (before it was initialized) or too many deletes.

The last thing you will want to double check is that there are no buffer over/under-runs. The new[] operator places some metadata on the heap that the delete[] operator uses to know the size of the array so it can properly cleanup the memory. Corrupting this metadata can result in heap corruption.

Comment: Sorry it took me forever to get back to this.  But the problem did end up being a buffer overrun.  I had to learn how to set pageheap.exe from the globalflags program and then use WinDbg to find it, but I did find where I was causing a heap corruption and fixed it.  Thanks for you help, everone.

Comment: Application Verifier from Microsoft is another tool you could use that works nicely to find these kinds of issues. It's very helpful